# Map Search Results

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, google-maps, mapkit

I am trying to provide useful information on an area to users based on a search term and their location.

I thought googles geo api would return a best match list of results for a query such as "swimming+pool+'my location' that I could then place an annotation for each result in my map view but it only returns one best match location.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google gecoder only handles addresses. Google provide a completely separate API which will geocode business names and categories, the Google AJAX Search API in [Local Search](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/local.html) mode

Answer (score 1):

Bing's map api will return multiple results for a business search near a location - which is essentially what you're doing. Unsure about Google's results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Google's HTTP API for business info. You should take a look at Yelp or Foursquare's APIs, I think.